# How to make a txt file from find with filenames and filename replaced with all [a-yA-Y]

Tags: command-line, bash, unix

I would like to ask for an UNIX one-liner to make this

I get the filenames by  `find . -type f > filenames.txt` that is fine
but I would like to get a text file looking like this:

```
   filename;filenamekey
   ./fn123456789X-5.txt;./123456789X5.
```

the second field should be the filename replaced by all chars ([a-yA-Y] but the numbers. The reason is that this field consits of ISBNs (consists 0-9 and X)then which is my key filed.

then I search in filenamekey like this 
`Select filename from books where filenamekey like '%123456789X%';`

In the filenames there need not to be an ISBN but it can. In the case of no ISBN the key should be empty or junk.

I tried this:

```
    find . -type f > filenames1.txt
    cat filename1.txt | sed -e 's/[^0-9X\/\.]//g' > filenamekey1.txt
    paste filename1.txt filenamekey1.txt | awk '{print $1,$2}'
```

would there be a sophisticated one-liner ?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ok David, I have done this only for the filenames and did the replace job in my delphi programm. As I am not so familar with unix one-lines it could be a more sophisticated way to do it before I import the txt file into my MYSQL Table. I could do it in more step like create the wholefilenames put it in a file and then reprocess it by grep-ing the filenames and put that in another file. But I am sure, there are some smart freaks that can do it by one unix one-liner.

Comment: You can do it in two basic ways. (1) `find . -type f -exec command parameters {} parameters \;`, where _command_ and _parameters_ are the processing you need, and each file name found replaces `{}` (which can be repeated, up to the terminating `\;`). If it is more complex, then you can incorporate the commands into a script and pass `{}` as a parameter. (2) `find . -type f | while read name; do commands ... ; done`, where _commands_ use `"$name"` for each file found.

Comment: @AFH thanks a lot. I tried this now but I miss here the second field `find . -type f | while read name; do echo $name | sed -e 's/[^0-9\/\.]//g' | awk '{print $1,";",$2}' ; done ` Any Idea what here is wrong?

Comment: I found my mistake: I tried this now: `find . -type f | while read name; do ohne="$(sed -e 's/[^0-9X\/\.]//g' <<< $name)"; echo $name,";",$ohne; done `

Comment: You are being needlessly complex: you don't need the `while` loop if all you need is the name to be in the input stream - it already is, so `find . -type f | sed -e 's/[^0-9\/\.]//g' | awk '{print $1,";",$2}'` is equivalent. As for what's wrong, where's the second `awk` parameter coming from?

Comment: @AFH thanks for your advice. OK, I have understood that the $2 is nonsense. but the `find . -type f | sed -e 's/[^0-9\/\.]//g' `makes only one columns - as I have understood it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `sed`:

```
find . -type f | sed 'h;s/[^0-9X\/\.]//g;H;x;s/\n/;/'
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT, that was I was looking for. Smart, short and sohpisticated!

Comment: One More Question: How must I modify your one-liner that I would like to get this out of the scirpt: `"./123456789XTest";./123456789X` YOu see the first field is quoted by " THANKS A LOT!

Comment: try `sed 'h;s/[^0-9X\/\.]//g;H;x;s/^/"/;s/\n/";/'`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
find . -type f | sed 's/[-a-zA-Z\.\/]//g'' > filenames.txt
```

Comment: I think the filenames.txt here is only one column. I need 2 columns first the whole untouched filename and second the sed-ed filename.